# PrivateObject in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net-core, mstest

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and in a MSTest Test Project (.NET Core) I am trying to use `PrivateObject` to test a protected method.

For example, I'm trying to do something like following

```
PrivateObject private = new PrivateObject(new Color())
```

But I get the following error

> PrivateObject could not be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I am also including

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

which I thought would include `PrivateObject`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type or namespace name 'PrivateObject' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273228/the-type-or-namespace-name-privateobject-could-not-be-found) or [How to unit test private method in .Net Core application which does not support “PrivateObject”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59678504/150605)

Answer (score 2):

I think `PrivateObject` does not exist in .Net Core.
You can use these extensions to invoke non public members.

```
public static T CallNonPublicMethod<T>(this object o, string methodName, params object[] args)
        {
            var type = o.GetType();
            var mi = type.GetMethod(methodName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            if (mi != null)
            {
                return (T)mi.Invoke(o, args);
            }

            throw new Exception($"Method {methodName} does not exist on type {type.ToString()}");
        }

public static T CallNonPublicProperty<T>(this object o, string methodName)
        {
            var type = o.GetType();
            var mi = type.GetProperty(methodName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            if (mi != null)
            {
                return (T)mi.GetValue(o);
            }

            throw new Exception($"Property {methodName} does not exist on type {type.ToString()}");
        }
```

And you can use them like this:

```
var color= new Color();
var result= color.CallNonPublicMethod<YourReturnType>(YourMethodName, param1, param2, ... param n);
```

Comment: i tried var color = new color() and then var result = color.CallNonPublicMethod<String>(getSizes); but it didn't work

Comment: @Golfer1145 How didn't it work?  Please be specific; "it didn't work" doesn't tell Kristjan what is wrong.

Comment: You should have "GetSizes"  as a string. Do you have a  valid GetSizes method with no arguments? Show us what do you get. A compilation error, runtime exception?